# Approximating an integral in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I've been trying to implement the following integral in MATLAB

[image]
Given a number n, I wrote the code that returns an array with n elements, containing approximations of each integral.

First, I tried this using a 'for' loop and the recurrence relationship on the first line. But from the 20th integral and above the values are completely wrong (correct to 0 significant figures and wrong sign).

The same goes if I use the explicit formula on the second line and two 'for' loops.

As n grows larger, so does the error on the approximations.

So the main issue here is that I haven't found a way to minimize the error as much as possible.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of the code and the resulting values, using the second formula:
[image]

This integral, for positive values of n, cannot have values >1 or <0

Comment: Without showing the relevant part of your code it is hard for us to help.

Comment: @Michael could copy-paste your code into your answer instead of the screenshot? Refer to [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to embed code. Also, please try to provide a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Even the first number doesn't seems correct. Could you check what `exp(1)` is?

Comment: @Yvon actually, in the picture it starts from the second integral. It must have been cut out on the screenshot, sorry (it is 6.3212....77e-001)

Comment: Add your code as text (not as an image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First attempt:

I tried the iterative method and found interesting thing. The approximation may not be true for all `n`. In fact if I keep track of `(n-1)*I(n-1)` in each loop I can see

```
I = zeros(20,3);
I(1,1) = 1-1/exp(1);
for ii = 2:20
    I(ii,2) = ii-1;
    I(ii,3) = (ii-1)*I(ii-1,1);
    I(ii,1) = 1-I(ii,3);
end
```

[image: iterative method result]

There is some problem around n=18. In fact, I18 = 0.05719 and 18*I18 = 1.029 which is larger than 1. I don't think there is any numerical error or number overflow in this procedure.

---

Second attempt:

To make sure the maths is correct (I verified twice on paper) I used `trapz` to numerically evaluate the integral, and n=18 didn't cause any problem.

```
>> x = linspace(0,1,1+1e4);
>> f = @(n) exp(-1)*exp(x).*x.^(n-1);
>> f = @(n) exp(-1)*exp(x).*x.^(n-1)*1e-4;
>> trapz(f(5))

ans =

     1.708934160520510e-01

>> trapz(f(17))

ans =

     5.571936009790170e-02

>> trapz(f(18))

ans =

     5.277113416899408e-02

>>
```

[image: numerical result]

A closer look is as follows. I18 is slightly different (to the 4th significant digit) between the (stable) numerical method and (unstable) iterative method. 18*I18 is therefore possible to exceed 1.

```
I = zeros(20,3);
I(1,1) = 1-1/exp(1);
for ii = 2:20
    I(ii,2) = ii-1;
    I(ii,3) = (ii-1)*I(ii-1,1);
    I(ii,1) = 1-I(ii,3);
end

J = zeros(20,3);
x = linspace(0,1,1+1e4);
f = @(n) exp(-1)*exp(x).*x.^(n-1)*1e-4;
J(1,1) = trapz(f(1));
for jj = 2:20
    J(jj,1) = trapz(f(jj));
    J(jj,2) = jj-1;
    J(jj,3) = (jj-1)*J(jj-1,1);
end
```

[image: numerical iterative comparison]

I suspect there is an error in each iterative step due to the nature of numerical computations. If the iteration is long, the error propagates and, unfortunately in this case, amplifies rapidly. In order to verify this, I combined the above two methods into a hybrid algo. For most of the time the iterative way is used, and once in a while a numerical integral is evaluated from scratch without relying on previous iterations.

```
K = zeros(40,4);
K(1,1) = 1-1/exp(1);
for kk = 2:40
    K(kk,2) = trapz(f(kk));
    K(kk,3) = (kk-1)*K(kk-1,1);
    K(kk,4) = 1-K(kk,3);
    if mod(kk,5) == 0
        K(kk,1) = K(kk,2);
    else
        K(kk,1) = K(kk,4);
    end
end
```

If the iteration lasts more than 4 steps, error amplification will be large enough to invert the sign, and starts nonrecoverable oscillation.

[image: hybrid result]

The code should be able to explain all the data structures. Anyway, let me put some focus here. The second column is the result of `trapz`, which is the numerical integral done on the non-iterative integration definition of I(n). The third column is (n-1)*I(n-1) and should be always positive and less than 1. The forth column is 1-(n-1)*I(n-1) and should always be positive. The first column is the choice I have made between the `trapz` result and iterative result, to be the "true" value of I(n).

As can be seen here, in each iteration there is a small error compared to the independent numerical way. The error grows in the 3rd and 4th iteration and finally breaks the thing in its 5th. This is observed around n=25, under the case that I pick the numerical result in every 5 loops since the beginning.

---

Conclusion: There is nothing wrong with any definition of this integral. However the numerical error when evaluating the expressions is unfortunately aggregating, hence limiting the way you can perform the computation.

Comment: "The approximation may not be true for all n", indeed, even if the first calculation has a very small error and the rest is "correctly calculated", the error is still carried and amplified. Now, on why the approximations still fail on the non-recursive formula (especially n-1=18), may be due to MATLAB being able to only calculate on e+016, while factorial(18)=6.140..706 e+015. Great work! Give me some time to have a detailed look at this and I will get back to you as soon as I can. (What's interesting, on a first look is "trapz" which seems to calculate more precicely.)

Comment: @Michael `eps(factorial(16:19))` try this

Comment: Hmm what does this return?

Comment: Since you have >1000 rep can you create a chat room so this isn't very extensive?